# Registering changes by Identity user (ASP .NET CORE) to column in table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am looking for a solution to register changes made to a database through an application by user level, using Microsofts Identity on ASP .NET core. I thought I would be able to track the changes on SQL server level, since all identityUsers are registered in it but haven't been able to find a solution.

I know it is possible to register by database user(principals), which I have a solution for, but for this to work, I would have to create users based on every single perceivable scenario in the SQL server before delivering to the end users, which is not something that would work with them.

As it seems to be very difficult to find any information on the subject, are there anyone who can point me in the right direction? Preferrably a Server-side solution but anything that registers update, create etc. will be deeply appreciated.

Cheers
Kasper

Comment: It is called Audit Trail. You can find a lot of solutions and libraries by googling `EF Core Audit Trail`.

Comment: Much appreciated!